# How to finish a handler before finishing an application?

Tags: android

Here is the thing I have a handler that shows a message on screen when I touch an area where the color of the background is white.

```
                  else if (ct.closeMatch (Color.WHITE, touchColor, tolerance))             

                               {  Random r = new Random();
                           int txt= r.nextInt(6-0) + 0;
                           if(txt==0){ variables.pointtxt = "Nothing interesting"; }
                           else if (txt==1){ variables.pointtxt = "There´s nothing there"; }     
                           else if (txt==2){ variables.pointtxt = "I can´t do nothing with that"; } 
                           else if (txt==3){ variables.pointtxt = "Wait... nop nothing"; }  
                           else if (txt==4){ variables.pointtxt = "Nothing"; }  
                           else if (txt==5){ variables.pointtxt = "More nothing"; }
                                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                                  View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);  
                                       final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                                          popupView, 
                                          LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,  
                                                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                          TextView text = (TextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.popuptxt);
                                        text.setText(variables.pointtxt);

                                        popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 250) ;




                                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
                                {
                                    public void run()
                                      {      if (popupWindow.isShowing()== true)

                                         popupWindow.dismiss();

                                      }
                                }, 1000);




                                   }
```

But if I run a new intent in les than 1000 miliseconds it crashes, I´m pretty sure because it couldn finish the handler cue.

Is it any way to tell the handler that if the aplication is closing then run popupWindow.dismiss(); ?

or inted is there a way to tell when I call ( when touching something red )

```
   if (ct.closeMatch (Color.RED, touchColor, tolerance)) {


                       Intent game = new Intent(lvl2_1_0.this, lvl2_1_1.class); 
                       game.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                          game.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                        startActivity(game);



                  }
```

To finish all handler cues?

I´v been searching and I can´t find a way to force finish all the handlers in an aplication before finishing it.

I know I´m pushing it a little maybe but in some cases when I test the game it crashes, of course maybe in normal playing it won´t happen because it´s unprobable to press the button to pass the screen in les than 1000 milliseconds after apearing the popup But it bothers me to have that error on my hands.

**Thanks to your answers in other threads I´v learned the most about programing for android so THANK YOU !**

This is the code Fixed Thanks to sam ! :P

```
public class lvl2_1_0 extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {
private PopupWindow popupWindow;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable dismissPopup = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (popupWindow.isShowing())
                popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    };
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

Then

call the popup. In my case:

```
   LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                                  View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);  
                                  popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                                          popupView, 
                                          LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,  
                                                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                          TextView text = (TextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.popuptxt);
                                        text.setText(variables.pointtxt);

                                        popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 250) ;



                                        mHandler.postDelayed(dismissPopup, 3000);
```

Finally close the aplication in without Force close

```
                       Intent game = new Intent(lvl2_1_0.this, lvl2_1_1.class); 
                       game.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                          game.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                          mHandler.removeCallbacks(dismissPopup);
                        startActivity(game);
```

Comment: What do you mean with reformat?

I edited it adding some code missing. I have other colors involving other actions but that works just fine. The problem seams to be when I close the aplication without waiting the 1000 miliseconds of the handler. If I wait it works fine but I don´t want the user to wait.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't clear. Please remove the extra spaces and tabs, it makes the code hard to read.

Comment: Just you go on this link and solve your problem,

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819140/how-to-stop-handler-in-android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819140/how-to-stop-handler-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But if I run a new intent in les than 1000 miliseconds it crashes, I´m pretty sure because it couldn finish the handler cue.

[`Handler#removeCallbacks(Runnable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks%28java.lang.Runnable%29) will cancel the passed Runnable f it is waiting in the queue.

Create two field variables to save a reference to your Handler and Runnable:

```
public class Example extends Activity {
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable dismissPopup = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (popupWindow.isShowing())
                popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Now where you previously called `new Handler().postDelayed(new R...` use:

```
mHandler.postDelayed(dismissPopup, 1000);
```

Finally just before you launch the new Intent call:

```java
...
mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);`
startActivity(game);
```

(You might want to call `removeCallbacks()` in `onPause()` as well.)

Comment: How do yoy save a reference of a handler or the runnable?

Comment: I simply meant: `Handler mHandler = new Handler();` and the same for your Runnable.

Comment: XD fancy talk XD

with that i have a problem i don´t know exactly where to call it I´m drowning on a glass of water.

do I have to call `Handler mHandler = new Handler()` twice? before closing aplication and before making the runable?
thanks anyway, I´ll keep diging

Comment: if I use private "Illegal modifier for parameter dismissPopup; only final is permitted"
:S

Comment: Are you creating them as field variables? (Outside of `onCreate()` and every other method.)

Comment: yes, but i´m having problems with the popupwindow part.

 `private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable dismissPopup = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (popupWindow.isShowing())
                popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    }`

it has a format and it´s not defined yet.

Comment: Oh... Create another field variable, `private PopupWindow popupWindow` (no final).

Comment: GREATE !
Testing right now

I should build you a monument for this :p