# Get a continuous touch coordinates

Tags: java, android, android-studio, touch, continuous

I want to continuously keep receiving the touch coordinates when finger is in the same exact place meaning getting the

```
CASE.MOVE_DOWN
```

Continuously.

Now the problem is android only gives

```
CASE.MOVE_UP
CASE.MOVE_DOWN
CASE.MOVE_MOVE
```

So is there anyway to getting Continuous touch..???

Comment: no, there is no such thing like "Continuous touch"

Comment: yeah i know but i want to keep sending the value where it is touched continuously..?? how can i acheive that i tried while loop but that crashed the app

Comment: what do yiu need it for?

Comment: i need to send it to ardunio for controlling purposes

Comment: so use some `Handler` and continuously send `Message`s to it

Comment: hmm i have never used handler can u plz guide to it and thx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819140/how-to-stop-handler-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
double placeX, placeY;
yourView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        placeX = event.getX(); //Store the coordinates of the touch in the meantime
        placeY = event.getY();
        return true;
    }
});
```

[resource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22254574/6056221)

Comment: yeah i know that ,but i want the values repetatively where the finger is put on and keep it there so if i hold it is still giving values of that coordinates

Comment: @PuneetSharma it does... At least when I tested it