# Running request repeatedly with a timer in Android

Tags: java, android, timertask

I'm looking on a way to run this task repeatedly with the listener. Right now, this is working but I'm looking on a way to make it repeatedly every 10 seconds.

**Activity**

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        VolleyRequest.makeRequest(this, URL, listenerResponse, listenerError);

    }

    private static final String URL = "https://naqil.ma/random.php";
    private Response.Listener<JSONObject> listenerResponse = new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "Resonse " + response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    private Response.ErrorListener listenerError = new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "Error " + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    };
}
```

**Class making request**

`````
public class VolleyRequest {
    public static void makeRequest(Context context, String url,
                                   Response.Listener<JSONObject> listenerResponse, Response.ErrorListener listenerError) {

        JsonObjectRequest requestWeather = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, listenerResponse,
                listenerError);
        Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(requestWeather);

    }
}
````
`````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Adapted from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10156550/2711811 )

Basically use a handler to reschedule request every 10 seconds.  Handler is attached to main looper by virtue of creating it in `onStart`.

First, remove the `VolleyRequest.makeRequest` from `onCreate`.

Add members to `SecondActivity`:

```
private Handler myHandler;
private Runnable myRunnable;
```

In `onStart` of `SecondActivity` :

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // Start issuing VolleyRequests repeating every 10 seconds.
    myHandler = new Handler();
    myHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            SecondActivity.this.myRunnable = this;
            VolleyRequest.makeRequest(
                SecondActivity.this, 
                URL, 
                SecondActivity.this.listenerResponse, 
                SecondActivity.this.listenerError);
            SecondActivity.this.myHandler.postDelayed(this, 10000);

        }
    };
}
```

And stop the repeated requests when the activity is stopped: in `onStop` of `SecondActivity`:

```
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // check that it actually ran at least once - can't be null.
    if (myRunnable != null) {
        myHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
    }
}
```